# Table centered and responsive on screen

Tags: html, ios, css

I am working on a mobile app. So I need to be responsive and fit the device on width and height. I dont know how work with images and tables to get my target

This is my target

[image]

But this is what i get with CSS code

[image]

```
#tablebot{

position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;

}
```

And my HTML is this

```
<table id="tablebot">
<tr><td>..img..</td><td>..img</td></tr>
<tr><td>..img..</td><td>..img</td></tr>
<tr><td>..img..</td><td>..img</td></tr>
<tr><td>..img..</td><td>..img</td></tr>
</table>
```

Where img is a src with width=100% and height=auto

I need the img on each cell responsive to device screen and the table centered

I tried with vertical aling

Thanks!!

Comment: Try and work it out in a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/2cLbn2gc/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert the table inside a container div, and then give it a `margin: 0 auto`. In the code snipped I readjusted the table width to 90% instead of 100% just to check that it's working:

```css
#tablebot{

position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 90%;
height: auto;

}

img {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table id="tablebot">
    <tr><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""> </td><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td><td><img src="https://unsplash.it/200" alt=""></td></tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```